# MIDI Sequence, Note on commands not always followed by note off

Tags: java, sequence, midi

Greetings and salutations fellow coders,

I'm trying to parse a MIDI sequence and get note durations from it.  When I get a note on command I do a look ahead to find either a note off command for the same key or a note on command with a velocity of 0.  Here is the code block in question(probably not needed).

```
for (Track track : sequence.getTracks()) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < track.size(); i++) 
    {
        MidiEvent event = track.get(i);
        MidiMessage message = event.getMessage();

        if (message instanceof ShortMessage) 
        {
            ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) message;
            long timeStamp = event.getTick();
            String temp = "0x" + Integer.toHexString(sm.getCommand());

            if (temp.contains(Definitions.NOTE_ON))
            {
                // look ahead for note off and find duration

                for (int j = i; j < track.size(); j++) 
                {
                    MidiEvent event2 = track.get(j);
                    MidiMessage message2 = event2.getMessage();

                    if (message2 instanceof ShortMessage)
                    {
                        ShortMessage sm2 = (ShortMessage) message2;
                        long timeStamp2 = event2.getTick();
                        temp = "0x" + Integer.toHexString(sm2.getCommand());

                        if (temp.contains(Definitions.NOTE_OFF) && sm2.getData1() == sm.getData1()) 
                        {
                                song.addNote(trackNumber, sm.getData1(), timeStamp, timeStamp2 - timeStamp, sm.getData2());
                                break;
                        }
                            //another valid way of turning a note off is playing a note on with a velocity of 0
                        else if (temp.contains(Definitions.NOTE_ON) && sm2.getData1() == sm.getData1() && sm2.getData2() == 0)
                        {
                            song.addNote(trackNumber, sm.getData1(), timeStamp, timeStamp2 - timeStamp, sm.getData2());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Definitions.NOTE_ON = "0x9"

Definitions.NOTE_OFF = "0x8"

The code is a little messy and definitely not optimized, but it shouldn't entirely be necessary for people with great expertise in midi.  I should note that most MIDI files I read use note off for the corresponding note on.  So most the songs I read are read successfully there are just a few that don't use note off and my application is not adding the notes.

My question is this:
What other ways than note off or note on with a velocity of 0 determines when a note stops playing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the ways I know to stop a MIDI note:

1. Call "Note Off" (0x80)
2. Call "Note On" (0x90) with velocity of 0
3. Call "All Notes Off" (0x58)

Also, a second Note On event for a given channel and note can be received without having received a Note Off. In this case, I believe the original Note On should be considered finished.

Comment: Awesome the command 0x58 did fix some of the songs that I was trying to read.  There are still a couple songs returning bad note data, it may be an issue with my code or in fact the midi files.  I'll mark you as an answer when I verify that these are the only commands that turn a note off, until then I will keep it open to receive additional answers.

Comment: Is it possible that some notes don't actually get turned off, they just decay away?

Comment: Alright!  It was an error in my code thankfully.  Every song is loading correctly I even double checked them with MidiEditor.  Thanks!